# Node js module.exports not exporting variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am new to node.js.  I was working with `module.exports` and I have an issue.  I have two files:

test.js

```
module.exports.lm="abc";
module.exports = "hello";
```

index.js

```
var p = require('./test.js');
var l = require('./test.js').lm
console.log(p); //hello
console.log(l); //undefined
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Unless you set `module.exports = "hello"` somewhere, that wouldn’t happen.

Comment: Ah, well, that’s a rather important difference. You’re adding something to the `module.exports` object and then replacing the entire object with a string. Even changing the order, though: string primitives can’t have their own properties.

Comment: One the one hand, you overwrite `.exports` after setting the property, on the other `"hello"` is a primitive string value and cannot have properties. So what exactly were you expecting to happen instead, and what parts don't you understand?

Answer (score 1):

As @Ryan said. The problem is that firstly you add `abc` to your `module.exports` and then you create completely a new object and assign string `hello` to it.

Try this code:

```
module.exports = {
  hello: "hello",
  lm: "abc",
};
```

Then you can import these variables like so:

```
var p = require('./test.js').hello;
var l = require('./test.js').lm
```